# Binding DataGridViewComboBoxColumn to a SQL data source

Tags: vb.net

I am attempting to create a userform that adds "template" data to a SQL server, them pulls that data back into a datagrid view on the form that will allow the user to input details.  Those details have constraints in the DB so I need combobox columns to validate entries in the grid.  At the moment I have the datagrid view built, it retreives data and adds the combobox columns, but I am not sure what the best way to send the details back to the server is.  If possible I would like to bind the combobox columns to the datasource.  Any sugestions on how to best proceed will be greatly appreciated.  I will put code for the current build bellow.

```
        SQLCon.Open()
        'Form allows user to define a time frame 
        'spEmployeePoints takes parameters from form and adds the needed fields to the DB
        Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand("spEmployeePoints", SQLCon)
        sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wkStart", dtpWeekStart.Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"))
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wkID", wkID)

        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        'spEmployeePoints_DGV_LOAD retreives ROWID, Employee_ID, and Name from the DB and passes them to the datagridview
        Dim sqlcmd2 As New SqlCommand("spEmployeePoints_DGV_LOAD", SQLCon)
        sqlcmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        sqlcmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wkStart", dtpWeekStart.Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"))
        sqlcmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wkID", wkID)

        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds = New DataSet()
        da.SelectCommand = sqlcmd2
        da.Fill(ds)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

        'Adding DataGridViewComboBoxColumn that corospond with DB columns not brought in by spEmployeePoints_DGV_LOAD
        '  Need comboboxes so the form validation will match the CHECK constraint in the DB
        DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(3, cbMon)
        DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(4, cbTue)
        DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(5, cbWed)
        DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(6, cbThu)
        DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(7, cbFri)
        DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(8, cbSat)
        DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(9, cbSun)
        DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(10, cbBonus)

        'The form is structured the way tha I intend, now is there a way to bind the combobox columns back to the DB,
        '   something like, bind combobox column where combobox rowid = db rowid
```

So after the user has created the template, I would like the details to transmit back to the server, but I was only able to figurer how to add the combobox columns as added columns, not as a part of the loaded sql data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select from SQL Server into DataGridView.

```
Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    connetionString = "Data Source=Your_Server_Name_Here;Initial Catalog=Test;Trusted_Connection=True;"
    connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
    sql = "Select * from Orders"
    Try
        connection.Open()
        adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(Sql, connection)
        adapter.Fill(ds)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Or...

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim connection As SqlConnection
    Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim cmdBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim changes As DataSet
    Dim sql As String
    Dim i As Int32

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password"
        connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
        Sql = "select * from Product"
        Try
            connection.Open()
            adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(Sql, connection)
            adapter.Fill(ds)
            connection.Close()
            DataGridView1.Data Source= ds.Tables(0)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Try
            cmdBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
            changes = ds.GetChanges()
            If changes IsNot Nothing Then
                adapter.Update(changes)
            End If
            MsgBox("Changes Done")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

http://vb.net-informations.com/dataadapter/dataadapter-datagridview-sqlserver.htm

Comment: Still running into a few bumbs but I think I know where they are comming from now.  Thanks for the assist.